# Use group_by to select all previous grouping levels in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on implementing a sequential testing procedure which takes values for users split in two different conditions each day and compute a t-test (p.value) from this sample.

```
df <- data.frame(
        date = rep(1:3,each=30),
        condition = sample(1:2,90,rep=T),
        value = rnorm(90,5,5)
        )

df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(test_out = t.test(value~condition)$p.value)
```

This outputs the test results per day. However, my goal is to take all previous dates when summarising the output so that the test results represent all data collected so far (the vector grows at each grouping).

So in this case, for date 1 I would have a p-value on all values for date 1, for date 2 I would have a p-value on all values for date 1:2, etc. I am unable to solve this with dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find out all the `unique` dates and in each iteration add one date to `filter` the dataframe with those dates and calculate the p-value. We can use `map_dfr` to get final output as a data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
vals <- unique(df$date)

map_dfr(seq_along(vals),~
     df %>% 
        filter(date %in% vals[1:.x]) %>% 
        summarise(date = .x, test_out = t.test(value~condition)$p.value))

#  date   test_out
#1    1 0.00595657
#2    2 0.18614978
#3    3 0.13357542
```

We can cross check the above values manually

```
df %>% filter(date %in% 1) %>% summarise(test_out = t.test(value~condition)$p.value)
#    test_out
#1 0.00595657
df %>% filter(date %in% c(1, 2)) %>% summarise(test_out = t.test(value~condition)$p.value)
#   test_out
#1 0.1861498
df %>% filter(date %in% c(1, 2, 3)) %>% summarise(test_out = t.test(value~condition)$p.value)
#   test_out
#1 0.1335754
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
     date = rep(1:3,each=30),
     condition = sample(1:2,90,rep=T),
     value = rnorm(90,5,5)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not `dplyr`-bound you could first create a list of subsets, then run a `sapply()` over it after.

```
subs <- lapply(mapply(":", 1, 1:3), function(x) df[df$date %in% x, ])
sapply(subs, function(x) with(x, t.test(value ~ condition)$p.value))
# [1] 0.00595657 0.18614978 0.13357542
```

***Data***

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date=rep(1:3, each=30),
                 condition=sample(1:2, 90, rep=TRUE),
                 value=rnorm(90, 5, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think this still produces the p-values per grouping level. Or, its the same as `df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(t.test(value~condition)$p.value)`

Comment: Thanks for your critique! Finally added the base R answer now, tell me what you think.

Comment: It does create an extra step by subsetting (which might affect processing for the data volume I have) but also does the trick, thanks! (upvoted)

Comment: Just combine the lines into one: `sapply(lapply(mapply(":", 1, 1:3), function(x) df[df$date %in% x, ]), function(x) with(x, t.test(value ~ condition)$p.value)))`. According to `microbenchmark` it's actually twice as fast.

Comment: :) yes, verified, interesting!